# KOTLIN: What does `?` mean in property type?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to kotlin. Can anyone explain me this line of code? Particularly what `?` means here in type?

```
private var verificationId: String? = null
```

Comment: Nullable type, which means it can be either String or null.

Comment: I don't think that this question is legitimate, as language documentation for Kotlin is simple and as questions like that can be easily looked up in the documentation, not enough effort have been shown.

Comment: That's a valid observation, yet there is no flag for that; Stackoverflow has nothing against questions you'd answer RTFM to, you just have to make sure it's not duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

This is a Nullable type, meaning it can be either a `String` or `null`

You can find more information [here](http://kotlin-quick-reference.com/152-R-nullable-types.html) and [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)

Comment: Oh got it. Thanks for clearing as I was assuming something else because I am coming from JS background